# Boolean vs algebraic circuits difference

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, boolean-functions, dc.parallel-comp, arithmetic-circuits

Valiant, Skyum, Berkowitz and Rackoff in https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0212043 showed that $VP=VNC^2$, namely, that arithmetic circuits can be parallelized.

> What is the central reason such a proof fails in boolean world (implying $P\neq NC$ should be true)?

Comment: In Boolean circuits, you have $x^2=x$, hence, you cannot really use the notion of degree that exists in polynomials over a field. This is crucial in VSBR (to make the circuit homogeneous and to define $f(v;w)$, later called the derivative of $v$ wrt $w$).

Comment: Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Stated other way, you *can* take a Boolean circuit, reinterpret it as an arithmetic circuit, and try to apply [VSBR]. But the circuit will usually compute a polynomial of exponential degree, hence you will not get anything useful.